# Manifest merger failed when importing tableview

Tags: android, tableview

I wanted to use table view in my android application but i get the following error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(Curtain Club) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-37
    is also present at [de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:11:18-50 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-139:19 to override.
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "Calculator.curtainclub"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }   
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0' 
        compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0' 
        implementation 'com.android.support:wear:26.1.0'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile project(':jtds-1.3.1')
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    }
```

if i remove the table view library, my gradle syncs perfectly with no errors

Here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Curtain Club"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginLogout.login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Employees.AdminLogin" />
    <activity android:name=".Calculator.Calc_140_pattern"></activity>
</application>
```

Please note i have opted out some activity files because there is a lot and it wouldn't allow me to add the question because of too much code

Comment: post your manifest file as well

Comment: @scienticious posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest file replace this

```
android:label="Curtain Club"
```

with

```
@string/curtain_club
```

Now Go to your **strings.xml** file and write this

```
<string name="curtain_club">Curtain Club</string>
```

After that rebuild your project